# How to compare whether a path is in same folder or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, regex

i want to compare weather input path is in same folder or not

**Question:** input path is in same folder or not?

let say my current path is `f://learning/java`

now i'm in folder named `java` whichever `path` is directly belongs to `java`  my **function** should return `true`.

**suppose i have these many paths:**

1. `f://learning/java/first/`            **true**
2. `f://learning/java/1.java`            **true**
3. `f://learning/java/machine/learning`  **false**
4. `f://learning/java/a/b`               **false**
5. `f://learning/java/`                  **true**
6. `f://learning/f`                      **false**

i have **tried** like below one:

```js
function pathDirectlyBelongsToSameFoler(currentPath, incomingPath) {
  if (currentPath == incomingPath) return true;
  // other comparision code i don't know
}

var currentPath = 'f://learning/java';

console.log(pathDirectlyBelongsToSameFoler(currentPath, 'f://learning/java/first'));
console.log(pathDirectlyBelongsToSameFoler(currentPath, 'f://learning/java/1.java'));
console.log(pathDirectlyBelongsToSameFoler(currentPath, 'f://learning/java/machine/learning'));
console.log(pathDirectlyBelongsToSameFoler(currentPath, 'f://learning/java/a/b'));
console.log(pathDirectlyBelongsToSameFoler(currentPath, 'f://learning/java/'));
console.log(pathDirectlyBelongsToSameFoler(currentPath, 'f://learning/f'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a dynamic regex and test against incoming path

```js
function pathTester(currentPath, incomingPath) {
if(incomingPath == currentPath) return true
  currentPath += currentPath.endsWith('/') ? '' : '/'
  let reg = new RegExp(String.raw `^${currentPath}[^\/]*\/?$`)
  return reg.test(incomingPath)
}

var currentPath = 'f://learning/java';

console.log(pathTester(currentPath, 'f://learning/java/first'));
console.log(pathTester(currentPath, 'f://learning/java/1.java'));
console.log(pathTester(currentPath, 'f://learning/java/machine/learning'));
console.log(pathTester(currentPath, 'f://learning/java/a/b'));
console.log(pathTester(currentPath, 'f://learning/java/'));
console.log(pathTester(currentPath, 'f://learning/f'));
```

Comment: very nice solution, thanks alot for your help, **BUT** this one is returning `true` if `f://learning/Java/first`, **Note:** `J` is in capital

Comment: @skBangalore ``let reg = new RegExp(`^${currentPath}[^/]*/?$`)``

Comment: as @WiktorStribiżew indicated correctly you can simply leave the `i` flag